# Ordinary Differential Equations - Step by step

Tags: calculus, integration

hi i'm in first year calculus 2 Differential Equations, I'm having trouble with the steps of integrate the trig identity.

find the general solution of the equation *(1/x)y'= 4 cos (2x)*

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

First note $\frac1{x}y'=4\cos{2x} \Leftrightarrow y'=4x\cos{2x} \Leftrightarrow y=\int4x\cos{2x}\,dx.$ This integral can be done by a simple application of integration by parts.

$$y = \int4x\cos{2x}\,dx \\
 = 2x\sin{2x} - \int 2\sin{2x}\,dx \\
 = 2x\sin{2x}+\cos{2x}+C$$